# SPSS average multiple numerical variables

Tags: spss

Is there a way to average multiple numerical variables?

I mean not means(v1 v2 v3). But the average of v1 v2 v3 combined

Regads.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the within-case average,

```
COMPUTE casemean = mean(v1, v2, v3).
```

Comment: Hello JKP , thanks for the answer . Sorry I didn't explain well enough , I want to calculate the total average of multiple variables combined, like put columns one over the other and then calculate the total average.Regards

Comment: How is this different, then, from adding up the three variables and doing ordinary summary statistics on it?